# Имя * не существует в данном контексте

Tags: c#, wpf

**Пояснение**:
Хочу при нажатии на кнопку с номером (1-9) добавить этот номер в поле (называется "*resultBlock*").
Событие *ButtonNumber_Click* есть только у *Button1* (кнопка "1"), но подразумевается, что она есть у всех кнопок с числами.

**Вопрос**: Почему у меня выходит следующая ошибка? - Имя *resultBlock* не существует в данном контексте. (Номер ошибки *CS0103*).
Документация Microsoft мне не совсем помогла, потому что ранее в С# я сталкивался с данной проблемой и понимаю причину её появления, но..
Я также читал форумы и все говорят про неправильное название каких-то элементов, namespace`ов. Если это так, где именно мне нужно исправить имя? Файл (.cs) использует namespace *WpfApp1*.

[image: До запуска WPF приложения]
[image: После запуска WPF приложения]
[image: Так выглядит окно WPF приложения]

Привожу XAML код:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
<Grid x:Name="WindowRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="Silver" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" TextAlignment="Right" Text="" AutomationProperties.Name="resultBlock"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="/"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="1" AutomationProperties.Name="Button1" Click="ButtonNumber_Click"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="2" AutomationProperties.Name="Button2"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="3" AutomationProperties.Name="Button3"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="*"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="4" AutomationProperties.Name="Button4"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="5" AutomationProperties.Name="Button5"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="6" AutomationProperties.Name="Button6"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="-"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="7" AutomationProperties.Name="Button7"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="8" AutomationProperties.Name="Button8"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="9"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="+"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="C"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="0"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="AC"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Century Ghotic" FontSize="72" Content="="/>
</Grid>
```

Весь C#:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ButtonNumber_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            resultBlock.Text += this.Content;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите весь C# код того класса, где выдает вам ошибки. И да, `AutomationProperties.Name` -> `x:Name`. Ну и да, научитесь использовать привязки (binding), это основы основ WPF!

Comment: Я буквально только сегодня начал разбираться в WPF, поэтому многого могу не знать.
Обновил, теперь вы можете посмотреть весь код в файле.

Comment: Замените как я сказал выше `AutomationProperties.Name` на `x:Name` и будет все работать. `многого могу не знать` - вот я вам и советую начать познавать сразу правильное. Вот просто, уберите все `x:Name`, все `AutomationProperties`, ну и попробуйте так, при помощи привязок сделать эту задачу. Как сделаете, попробуйте избавиться от дубликатов (куча повторных кнопок в XAML), попробуйте это сгенерировать (достаточно привязать коллекцию к `ItemsControl`). Не бойтесь, это весьма просто, достаточно понять как это работает)

Comment: Сгенерировать же, на сколько я понимаю, придется в конструкторе, что не есть хорошо, разве нет?)

Comment: Зависит от подхода, как сделаете) Хоть сделайте `public List<int> Numbers {get;} = new(){1, 2, 3, 4, ...}`, привяжите, задайте стиль, ну и вот уже часть клавиатуры есть. А так, конструктор нужен для инициализации, логику лучше писать за его пределами (например, по событию `Loaded` окна вызывать метод).